# Should selected videos be compressed in iOS (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, video, uikit, compression

my app allows users to **pick media from their library**. With videos, as they can be quite heavy in size, compression *seems* to become interesting.

However, while picking, it is shown that the **video is already being compressed:**

[image: Compression Screen]

> At the bottom of the image you're able to see the blue progress bar saying "Compressing Video"

I'm making use of Apple's default UIImagePicker and therefore get a URL once the user has finished picking.

**This is the code I'm using to handle picks:**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] != nil else { return }
        let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as! CFString

        switch mediaType {

        case kUTTypeImage:
            // code removed for brevity

        case kUTTypeMovie:
            print("Movie!") // it's a movie!

            if let mediaUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL{
                print("Picked video with ending:", mediaUrl.path?.suffix(4)) // print out the video suffix
            }

            break

        default:
            print("Unknown media!")
        }

        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // dismiss the picker

    }
```

Until now, I've always compressed the file further, but I'm not sure if this makes any sense at all as iOS seems to already compress the file.

**I compressed it like this:**

```
let compressedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
                var compressedFileData : Data? =  nil

                compressVideo(inputURL: m.mediaUrl, outputURL: compressedURL, handler: { (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?) -> Void in

                    switch exportSession!.status {
                    case .completed:

                        print("Video compressed successfully")
                        do {
                            compressedFileData = try Data(contentsOf: exportSession!.outputURL!)

                            // Call upload function here using compressedFileData


                        } catch _ {
                            print ("Error converting compressed file to Data")
                        }

                    default:
                        print("Could not compress video")
                    }
                } )

            func compressVideo(inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ exportSession: AVAssetExportSession?)-> Void) {
                let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)
                guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {
                    handler(nil)
                    return
                }

                exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
                exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4 //AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie (m4v)
                exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
                exportSession.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
                    handler(exportSession)
                }
            }
```

**Any thoughts on this topic? Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: What do you mean by `I've always compressed the file further,`? Do you mean a lossless compression like gzip? Or re-encoding the video with a lower bitrate?

Comment: @szatmary sorry for the late response. I updated my question with the code I used. Do you have any idea if there's a better way to compress it or is compressing senseless at all? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ok, so you are doing a lossy, compression. No, its not useless. But you should check the file size before and after compression to know exactly how many bytes you are saving. and make a judgement from that.

Comment: @szatmary what is a lossy compression? And is there a way to compress it better/further?

Comment: You can google "lossy compression", and you need to define what is "better" for you. You're making a trade off, Is quality more or less important than file size to your application?

Comment: @szatmary it should be balanced; I don't need 4K videos, but I also don't want to have GB sized videos... I want to compress it as much as possible without loosing too much quality. I know that this is a loose definition but I don't really know much about compression... Can you give any recommendation?

Comment: `Can you give any recommendation? ` yes, you need to learn a little bit about compression. At the very least you need to understand what a bitrate is. I can't give you a recommendation, because the likely hood my recommendation is not compatible with other assumptions you are making that I am unaware of is very high. I don't know what `too much quality` means to you. `don't want to have GB` just makes more questions than answers. If the video as 12 hours long, Its going to take gigabytes. unless the video has very little motion, or is low resolution. There are just to many variables.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but here is a data point: The `UIImagePickerController` took a random, 19 sec, 256mb, 3840×2160 video shot on iPhone 12 Pro Max, and reduced that to a 9.5mb 1280×720 video.